# Fedora Core yum update cpio error

Tags: yum, cpio

Any idea why I'm getting these errors when running:

```
yum update
```

http://pastie.org/private/7x4pez9duzxvmb6lgeyrgq

I've never had a problem with that command in the past.

Comment: Can you download an rpm from somewhere or scp it to that box and install. Are you able to do that? And also, you do have enough disk-space, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make some wild guesses, since i do not know anything about your system. Maybe it will help you troubleshoot, however, if you look for `yum` and `cpio` on Google, there are some threads discussing *similar* issues.

a) Corrupted `glibc` libraries

b) I possibility of filesystem corruption.

c) File system full

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when a package contains one type of file (normal, directory, symlink, etc.), but the file in the filesystem is of a different type. You can try using `yum shell` in order to remove the existing packages and install the new ones, instead of upgrading the packages in-place:

```
# yum shell
> remove somepackages
> install somepackages
> run
> exit
```